# Availability of the Menu Key

Tags: hardware

As seen on [backwards compatibility](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/compatibility.html) for the Android phones, do some phones always have traditional physical keys like the Menu Key, ususally on *Gingerbread* and older only? I was wondering if most modern phones running on *Jellybean* and *Ice Cream Sandwich* will always have virtual Action Overflow button in replace of the Menu Key.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real standard here — every manufacturer does whatever it likes. E.g., many Samsung devices (including Samsung Galaxy S4 and Samsung Galaxy Note II) use the traditional layout — Menu, Home, Back (with Menu and Back as touch keys, and Home as a physical key; and the Back key is really on the right side, while many other manufacturers place it on the left side). Given the Samsung market share, there is a significant number of phones shipped with recent Android versions and still having the Menu key.

Comment: Is that mean that the availability of the Menu Key may depend according the version of the phone brand? For example, some phones always have the physical Menu Key while other phones don't have the Menu Key but it appears as an Action Overflow regardless of the app?

Comment: The Action OVerflow can be programmed to be *visible* regardless if menu key is present or not.

Answer (score 1):

If the older devices have a menu key, the overflow action indicator will not show, this is by behaviour! See my answer on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480302/overflow-actions-on-actionbar-not-showing/11484595#11484595).

Comment: For switching app window, does it uses a hard Menu Button by default if this phone is available to have one?